# CodeNarc and Groovy: NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeStaticMethod

Tags: groovy, codenarc

I am trying to run codenarc and have below script for this but I have been getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeStaticMethod. I dont believe there are different version of jars in the script below that could cause this. Please help!!

```
@set GROOVY_JAR="D:\codenarc\apache-groovy-sdk-3.0.0-alpha-4\groovy-3.0.0-alpha-4\lib\groovy-3.0.0-alpha-4.jar"
@set NARC_JAR="D:\codenarc\CodeNarc-1.2.1.jar "
@set SLF2="D:\codenarc\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar"
@set GRV_JAR="D:\codenarc\groovy-1.0-jsr-06.jar"


echo "Running CodeNarc"

@java -classpath %GROOVY_JAR%;%GRV_JAR%;%NARC_JAR%;D:\codenarc\apache-groovy-sdk-3.0.0-alpha-4\groovy-3.0.0-alpha-4\lib\*.jar;D:\codenarc\apache-groovy-sdk-3.0.0-alpha-4\groovy-3.0.0-alpha-4\lib\extras-jaxb\*.jar;%SLF2% org.codenarc.CodeNarc -basedir=D:\src -rulesetfiles=file:D:\R2\GW_PC\rules.groovy -title=Rose -includes=**/*.gs,**/*.gsx
```

but i am getting below error:

```
ERROR: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeStaticMethod(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeStaticMethod(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at groovy.xml.streamingmarkupsupport.AbstractStreamingBuilder.<init>(AbstractStreamingBuilder.groovy)
        at groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder.<init>(StreamingMarkupBuilder.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:237)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:241)
        at org.codenarc.report.AbstractHtmlReportWriter.writeReport(AbstractHtmlReportWriter.groovy:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:352)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:68)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:184)
        at org.codenarc.report.AbstractReportWriter$_writeReportToFile_closure3.doCall(AbstractReportWriter.groovy:86)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1044)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:427)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.IOGroovyMethods.withWriter(IOGroovyMethods.java:1133)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ResourceGroovyMethods.withWriter(ResourceGroovyMethods.java:2022)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$1087.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:246)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:55)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
        at org.codenarc.report.AbstractReportWriter.writeReportToFile(AbstractReportWriter.groovy:85)
        at org.codenarc.report.AbstractReportWriter.this$2$writeReportToFile(AbstractReportWriter.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:190)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:58)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:176)
        at org.codenarc.report.AbstractReportWriter.writeReport(AbstractReportWriter.groovy:72)
        at org.codenarc.report.ReportWriter$writeReport.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:135)
        at org.codenarc.CodeNarcRunner$_execute_closure1.doCall(CodeNarcRunner.groovy:85)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1044)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:427)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2275)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2260)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2301)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$188.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:246)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:55)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
        at org.codenarc.CodeNarcRunner.execute(CodeNarcRunner.groovy:84)
        at org.codenarc.CodeNarcRunner$execute.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:119)
        at org.codenarc.CodeNarc.execute(CodeNarc.groovy:135)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:190)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:70)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
        at org.codenarc.CodeNarc.main(CodeNarc.groovy:111)
CodeNarc - static analysis for Groovy',
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm sure that's because you are using groovy-3

take groovy 2.5, and java 1.8 and everything should be fine